# How to link multiple Views of one Google Analytics Property to seperate bigquery projects/datasets

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We've got an App that runs in multiple countries for multiple companies which reside in different timezones. We track those using one Property and a view customer (with their filter + timezone). Is it possible, and if so how, to have multiple views of one property export to multiple Bigquery projects/datasets. Especially from the timezone point of view, as the exports are per day it's quite complex to query on date and time as such a field does not exist (or isn't it and is that the solution?).

Hope someone can assist.

Comment: This isn't related to coding and would be off topic, but it's not possible to link multiple views from one property to BQ. Only one view per property is linkable.

Comment: Agree on the non coding, but I've seen similair questions so assumed would be ok to post. If you have a source to confirm you claim that would make for a great answer.

Comment: I don't have any docs on hand, but more just anecdotal evidence and personal experience. Even in the interface alone there's no way to add multiple views. If you are using BQ, then you should have access to GA 360 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add only one BigQuery View per Property in Google Analytics.  You will not be able to send multiple Views within same Property.

I suggest that you send a consolidated view with all the timezones and then inside of BigQuery, add logic to split that data into multiple datasets based on the filters you would add in GA